# How to prove linear transformation->corresponding matrix?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

given linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, how can I prove that there is a unique matrix $A_{m  n}$ such that $T(v)=Av$ for $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

I know how to prove it the other way around(given matrix, proving it is a linear transformation), but I can't find a nice solution for this way.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Construct a matrix whose columns are the images of the basis vectors

Comment: The matrix representation of $T$ is not unique. It depends on the choice of bases for the domain and codomain. However, once you’ve fixed a pair of bases, then the matrix is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Let $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n$ be the vectors of the standard basis for $\mathbb R^n$. Let $A$ be the $m\times n$ matrix such that their $j$-th column is the vector $T(e_j)$, that is, $Ae_j = T(e_j)$. Then, for each $v\in\mathbb R^n$, $v$ can be written as
$$v = \sum_{i=1}^n v_ie_i$$
so,
$$\begin{align} 
T(v) = T\Big( \sum_{i=1}^n v_ie_i \Big) &= \sum_{i=1}^n v_iT(e_i) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n v_i(Ae_i) = A\Big( \sum_{i=1}^n v_ie_i \Big) \\
&= Av
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am still struggling with the next bit - proving that A is unique. If you set another set of basis and go through the same construction, call it B, would it be guaranteed that A=B? I can't justify why.

Comment: Well, if there is another matrix $B$, then, $Av = Bv$ *for all* $v\in\mathbb R^n$, in particular, $Ae_j = Be_j$ for all $j=1,2,\dots,n$, meaning that $A$ and $B$ has the same columns. Hence $A=B$.